# Instantiate UIViewController from Storyboard, viewDidLoad() not executed

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm creating a Slideout navigation controller.

Now I need to assign my MenuViewController and my TopViewController.

I have a TopViewController screen in a Storyboard that was using other type of slideout menu.

[image]

In my AppDelegate I have the following:

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard! = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let dashboard = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DashboardView") as! DashboardViewController

        let menu : SlideoutViewController = SlideoutViewController()
        menu.menuEnabled = true
        menu.topView = dashboard
        menu.menuView = SalesViewController()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController = menu as SlideoutViewController
```

But when doing this the `viewDidLoad` method in DashboardViewController is never reached, that means that the view has not been instantiated yet.

> Any clue?

**UPDATE**: this is a function `selectView` in slideout view controller

```
func selectView(viewController: UIViewController){

        if (_internalTopNavigation != nil)
        {
            _internalTopNavigation!.removeFromParentViewController();
            _internalTopNavigation!.view.removeFromSuperview();

        }

        _internalTopNavigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        _internalTopNavigation!.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                                  width: _internalTopView!.view.frame.width,
                                                  height: _internalTopView!.view.frame.height)

        _currentView = viewController;
        _internalTopView!.addChildViewController(_internalTopNavigation!);
        _internalTopView!.view.addSubview(_internalTopNavigation!.view);



        if (_menuEnabled == true)
        {
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = createMenuButton()
            viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        }


        _externalContentView = viewController;


    }
```

Comment: Can you show the interface for SlideoutViewController? Is it treating topView/dashboard as a child view controller? At what point in this process are the contents of the dashboard view controller appearing on screen, if at all?

Comment: I just updated the question, and added the function in slideoutviewcontroller that will show a viewcontroller. I guess yes is treating as a child view controller.

Comment: instead of putting dashboard in menu and making menu rootviewcontroller, try making dashboard as rootbiewcontroller directly and see if viewed load is called?